# Get Data from UserForm into existin Table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform, data-entry, excel-tables

I have a problem, I'm trying to add data from userform into existing Table which contains different formulas (Table 1) but I do not know how to insert that in the code. Here is the code:

(And the sheet where the table is, is Sheet1.)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = Sheet1

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

 AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = ComboBox2.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 3).Value = ComboBox3.Value
 AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox4.Value
 AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox8.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox11.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = TextBox6.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = TextBox7.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 15).Value = TextBox9.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 16).Value = TextBox10.Text
 AddNew.Offset(0, 14).Value = ComboBox1.Text

 TextBox1.Text = ""
ComboBox2.Text = ""
ComboBox3.Text = ""
ComboBox4.Text = ""
TextBox8.Text = ""
TextBox11.Text = ""
TextBox6.Text = ""
TextBox7.Text = ""
TextBox9.Text = ""
TextBox10.Text = ""
ComboBox1.Value = ""


End Sub
```

Comment: I have to admit, i don't see a question here.  The code as provided looks like it will work without error.  What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: It works, but it it adds the data in sheet1 and I want to add them in a particular table wich is situated in sheet1 and it's called "Table1"

Comment: You'll need to reference the table during your assignment of the AddNew range variable (currently you have it hard-coded to column A), like so: `Set AddNew = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, wks.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Answer (score 0):

@tigeravatar is right, you need to look up the documentation for ListObjects.

A table is different than a sheet in Excel.

As you progress in VBA, you're going to [want to use this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) to help you understand some of the magic happening.

In VBA, like .NET, variable classes have different properties and methods you can reference. If you make an object that is a specific pre-built class, there will most likely be documentation and tutorials available on the web for you to read, learn, and build on.